# How to add slide transition effects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wrote some code that makes an image slide correctly.  But i want to add a transition effect.

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "7.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "268939_234023119951136_1441221_n.jpg"
</script>

<p><img src="142357419110524688_932580683437050_8134682163687368860_n.jpg" width="500" height="300" name="slideaa" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<2)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using eval? eval("image"+step+".src");
couldn't you just do 'image' + step + '.src';